# Create function names using paste() in R

Tags: r, function

I would like to do the following

```
X = matrix(0, nrow = p, ncol = N)
p=5
N=100
for (i in 1:N)
{
X[1,i] = e1(t[i])
X[2,i] = e2(t[i])
X[3,i] = e3(t[i])
X[4,i] = e4(t[i])
X[5,i] = e5(t[i])
}
```

where e1(). e2(), e3(), e4() and e5() are specific functions.

I have tried the following code:

```
for(j in 1:p)
{
for (i in 1:N)
{
    X[j,i] = as.symbol(paste("e", j, sep = ""))(t[i])
}
}
```

But it does not work.

Thanks for your help

Carole

Comment: I think the question is not what you are entitling it. You are asking how to convert strings into function calls. The functions already exist and you are NOT creating names for them.

Answer (score 3):

You want the function `get`

```
for(j in 1:p)
{
for (i in 1:N)
{
    X[j,i] = get(paste("e", j, sep = ""))(t[i])
}
}
```

If e1 (etc) are vectorized, you can remove one of the loops:

```
for (j in 1:p) {
  X[j,] = get(paste0("e", j))(t)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use `do.call` :

```
R> myfun <- function(x) print(x)
R> do.call(paste0("my","fun"), list("foo"))
[1] "foo"
```

The first argument of `do.call` is the name of the function (you can use `paste` here), and the second one is a list of arguments to pass.